# Cannot read properties of undefined" and Constructor Issues

Tags: javascript, angular, openapi-generator

I've been facing issues while integrating an Angular SDK library that I've built. The errors I'm encountering are as follows:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
  'forRoot')

  - Due to constructor error.
- Uncaught TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor

What I've Done:

SDK Library Code (ApiModule)

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, SkipSelf, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class ApiModule {
  public static forRoot(configurationFactory: () => Configuration): ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ApiModule,
      providers: [{ provide: Configuration, useFactory: configurationFactory }]
    };
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: ApiModule, @Optional() http: HttpClient) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('ApiModule is already loaded. Import in your base AppModule only.');
    }
    if (!http) {
      throw new Error('You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule!');
    }
  }
}
```

Angular App (AppModule)
I'm importing ApiModule using forRoot:

```
import { ApiModule } from 'path-to-api-module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ApiModule.forRoot(() => new Configuration()),
    // ... other modules
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Configuration Factory
I've also attempted to use a Configuration factory function:

```
export function apiConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  const params: ConfigurationParameters = {
    basePath: "https://localhost:7054/",
  };
  return new Configuration(params);
}
```

**What I've Tried:**
Checked the imports and paths. Deleted node_modules and
package-lock.json, then reinstalled. Checked tsconfig.json for possible misconfigurations.

**Question:**

How can I resolve these issues?
Is there something I've missed in the SDK library code or Angular app code that's causing these issues?